# Ruby on rails application using Prawn gem for pdf generation makes an error while rendering: undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, prawn

**code in controller**

```
def download_report
  @downloads  = StatisticDownload.select("date(Date) as downloaded_date, count(id) as count").where("DownloadSuccess=?","1").group("date(Date)")
  respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf { @downloads }
  end
end
```

**Created view**

```
# download_report.pdf.prawn
pdf.text "Download ##{@downloads.id}", :size => 30, :style => :bold

downloads = @downloads.map do |downloads|
  [
    downloads.file,
    downloads.id
  ]
end
```

But ../generate_report.pdf generates an error: 
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.map

i have installed prawn 0.12.0 and prawnto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the whole `respond_to` block, so you will have:

```
def download_report
  @downloads  = StatisticDownload.select("date(Date) as downloaded_date, count(id) as count").where("DownloadSuccess=?","1").group("date(Date)")
end
```

**Alternatively,** if you really need the respond_to block, don't specify a block after `format.pdf`:

```
def download_report
  @downloads  = StatisticDownload.select("date(Date) as downloaded_date, count(id) as count").where("DownloadSuccess=?","1").group("date(Date)")
  respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf
  end
end
```

In both cases, I'm guessing you need to let prawnto's controller magic take over.

Answer (score 2):

For this refer the http://www.idyllic-software.com/blog/creating-pdf-using-prawn-in-ruby-on-rails/

you can find easy solution..